# Allow either one name or another to be selected when a person uses the code

Tags: java, applet

```html
<param name="userName" value ="Name1", "Name2", "Name3, "Name4";>
```

I am attempting force the user one of these names, name1, name2, or name3, whenever they uses the whole thing. It only seems to print out only the first name, Name1, as their name. Can anyone assist me with this, been trying for some time attempting to trigger a selection of one of the three names once the main java file is executed but don't seem to know the correct way to place this.

```html
<div>
<div id="656408534163754545" align="center" style="width: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;"         class="wcustomhtml">
<applet code="net.game.Launcher" archive="https://s3.amazonaws.com/GameDownload/launcher/GameLauncher.jar?v=1357737036000" codebase="/game/" width="854" height="480">
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.opengl=false -'Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false">
    <param name="userName" value ="Name1", "Name2", "Name3";>
    <param name="latestVersion" value="1357737036000">
    <param name="sessionId" value="none">
                    <param name="downloadTicket" value="fa6fa480be029f0e3f80dfaff8a9a9c0">
        </applet></div>
</div>
```

This is the full code.

Comment: How are you retrieving the name? You should include the code that's having the issue. We have **no** idea what's going on behind the scenes - unless you show us.

Comment: Edited in the full code. New to this website, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<param name="userName" value ="Name1", "Name2", "Name3";>
```

That is not valid HTML.  Check your HTML in an [HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).

```html
<param name="userName" value ="Name1, Name2, Name3" >
```

Is valid HTML, but unless the `Launcher` class splits them on the string, it is not going to produce the effect you seem to want.  Since that code was not written by you, I'd say this is not attainable.